# How to use two OS environment variables for string replacement

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

## The following constraints apply…

1. The version of **sed** available does not have the `–i` (in-place replacement) option.
2. In-place replace of the string is preferred over renaming files.
3. A single command is preferred.
4. Usable in a BASH 5.0.0(2) script, not just from an interactive command.

The following have been tried but do not seem to work because **sed** is a “one pass” tool.  I am assuming  the “one pass” design is why **sed** is not working.  As I read the manpage for the use of the **sub()** function in **awk** does not seem to take OS environment variables for string replacement.

### Environment variables…

```
PROP_FILE_PROP="Gleep00"
export PROP_FILE_PROP
echo "${PROP_FILE_PROP}"

PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE="Gleep_Value_00 Gleep_Value_01 Gleep_Value_02"
export PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE
echo "${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}"
```

### Subset of full file

```
.
.
.
# attachmentFilesWhiteList = css js html exe text/plain application/vnd.xfdl
attachmentFilesWhiteList = css js html exe application/pdf text/calendar text/plain application/vnd.xfdl mov avi mp4 webm ogg image/png doc docx xls xlsx ppt pptx jpg jpeg application/octet-stream
.
.
.
```

### Works…

```
sed "s/^attachmentFilesWhiteList =\ .*/attachmentFilesWhiteList =\ ${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}/"
```

**Successful Result**

```
.
.
.
# attachmentFilesWhiteList = css js html exe text/plain application/vnd.xfdl
attachmentFilesWhiteList = Gleep_Value_00 Gleep_Value_01 Gleep_Value_02
.
.
.
```

### Does not work…

```
sed "s/^${PROP_FILE_PROP} = .*/ ${PROP_FILE_PROP} = ${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}/"

sed "s/^${PROP_FILE_PROP} = / ${PROP_FILE_PROP} = ${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}/"

sed "s/^\"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" = / \"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" = \"${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}\"/"

sed "s/^\"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" = .*/ \"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" = \"${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}\"/"

sed "s/^\"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" = .*/\n \"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" = \"${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}\"/"

sed "s/^\"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" \= .*/\n \"${PROP_FILE_PROP}\" \= \"${PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE}\"/"
```

**Failure Result**

```
.
.
.
# attachmentFilesWhiteList = css js html exe text/plain application/vnd.xfdl
attachmentFilesWhiteList = css js html exe text/plain application/vnd.xfdl
.
.
.
```

Comment: [You have not explained what your input is, nor what your output is.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion).

Comment: Original post has been updated with the salient line in the text file and the good and bad results.

Comment: your first "doesn't work option", should work with the values you have shown for the $PROP_FILE_DROP (by the way, I'm assuming `PROP_FILE_PROP="Gleep00"` should read `PROP_FILE_PROP="attachmentFilesWhiteList"` - if not, here you go!). try using `set -x` to see what is happening

Comment: Original post has been updated with the addition of 4. to the "following constraints apply…" list.

Comment: You haven't showed us what you tried to do with awk. It certainly *can* access environment variables (as `$ENVIRON['varname']`), though the normal practice is to pass shell variables through the command line (`awk -v var="$var" ...`)

Comment: That said, nothing in your `sed` code requires `export`ing your shell variable into an environment variable. Generally, that should only be done when you have an explicit and meaningful reason to do so -- environment space is a limited resource, and it's shared with maximum command-line length; every variable you export reduces your max command-line length.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit a file, use a file editor :) `sed` is for editing *streams*.

```
ed tmp.txt <<EOF
/^attachmentFilesWhiteList/s/= .*/= $PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE
wq
EOF
```

Note that `PROP_FILE_PROP_NEW_VALUE` doesn't need to be exported; the shell expands the value in the here document before `ed` runs.